# VBA: Clear multiple discontiguous cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code right now:

```
Sub ClearTimeline()
    Dim wsTimeline As Worksheet
    Set wsTimeline = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    wsTimeline.Range("B8, F25, F26, F28, F30, M17, M31, L17, L24:L25, L26, L28, L29:L30, J24:J25, J26, J28, J29:J30, K25, K26, K28, K30").ClearContents

End Sub
```

I want to replace the fixed cell reference by something more dynamic. The rows won't change, so I want to change how I reference the columns. I have a "reference cell", i.e. a cell I can always find/know the column of.

```
Sub ClearTimeline()
    Dim wsTimeline As Worksheet
    Dim referenceDay As Long

    Set wsTimeline = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    referenceDay = 10

'what works:
    wsTimeline.Range(wsTimeline.Cells(referenceDay - 9, 1)).ClearContents 'clears single cell

    wsTimeline.Range(wsTimeline.Cells(referenceDay - 9, 1), wsTimeline.Cells(referenceDay - 1, 1)).ClearContents 'clears range

End Sub
```

My goal is to refer to every column as 'referenceDay +/- X' because the distance to this day will stay the same even if the sheet is altered in some other way. But how do I tell Excel to do the same action for non-contiguous cells? I'm not sure how to reference them and what to put into the parentheses after `wsTimeline.Range`

Comment: What's the pattern or logic that determines the columns? Seems like maybe it's a mix of several rules?

Comment: You need to create a range objct using `Union` and then use that :)

Comment: @BigBen Edited my post. I always want to add or subtract something from `referenceDay` because the distance between that cell and the cell I wanna reference will not change.

Comment: That is better detail, but your second snippet doesn't match the first one. `Cells(referenceDay - 9, 1)` is `A1` - how is that related to the hard-coded range in the first snippet? Maybe a screenshot of your setup would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the whole range of hardcoded cells should be moved to the right or to the left, depending on the column. `Offset()` is pretty good for this.

[image]

The "red" cells are the cells of the initial range, and the selected cells are the cells with the `Offset(columnoffset:=2)`. I have used `.Select` to illustrate the difference, because there is overlapping and colors would not have been ok:

```
Sub ClearTimeline()

    Dim wsTimeline As Worksheet
    Set wsTimeline = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim timelineRange As Range
    Set timelineRange = wsTimeline.Range("B8, F25, F26, F28, F30, M17, M31, L17, L24:L25, L26, L28, L29:L30, J24:J25, J26, J28, J29:J30, K25, K26, K28, K30")
    timelineRange.ClearContents
    timelineRange.Interior.Color = vbRed

    timelineRange.Offset(columnoffset:=2).Select 'But in general, do not use .Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah. I think this is what OP is looking for, but the detail was lacking.